# 7zip fails to unpack rar under Debian

Tags: debian, 7-zip

I have the following packages installed:

```
:~# apt search 7zip|grep installed

7zip/stable,now 22.01+dfsg-8 amd64 [installed]
libarchive13/stable,now 3.6.2-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
liblzma-dev/stable,now 5.4.1-0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
liblzma5/stable,now 5.4.1-0.2 amd64 [installed]
p7zip/stable,now 16.02+dfsg-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
p7zip-full/stable,now 16.02+dfsg-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
p7zip-rar/stable,now 16.02-3 amd64 [installed]
xarchiver/stable,now 1:0.5.4.20-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

But when I try to unpack rar files using 7zip or xarchiver, I get the following error

```
$ 7z ../Archive.rar 

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,32 CPUs AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5650GE with Radeon Graphics     (A50F00),ASM,AES-NI)



Command Line Error:
Unsupported command:
../Archive.rar
```

As said, the same error happens under xarchiver

Comment: BTW, you're using 7-Zip **16.04**,  seven years out of date! If you cannot find a current 7-Zip .deb version, the current Windows version, 23.01, runs well under *wine*. Not sure why Debian (and Ubuntu) do not keep that up-to-date. It also seems p7zip is not updated, either.

Comment: $ cat /etc/debian_version 12.4 Well Debian again with outdated binaries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`7z` requires the first argument to be a command it understands. The command to extract files with full paths is `x`.

```
7z x ../Archive.rar
```

There are other commands. See [`man 1 7z`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/p7zip-full/7z.1.en.html).

Comment: Ok thanks wonder why it fails in xarchiver too tho.